# how caching is implemented using PHP GD

Tags: php, gd

I want to cache the images of my gallery. Generating images every pages load using GD uses a lot of memory, So I am planning to create a cache image for the images generated by php script done with GD. What will be the best thing to create cache?

Answer (score 5):

Use something like

```
$mime_type = "image/png";
$extension = ".png";
$cache_folder = "cache";

$hash = md5($unique . $things . $for . $each . $image);
$cache_filename = $cache_folder . '/' . $hash . $extension;

//Is already it cached?
if($file = @fopen($cache_filename,'rb')) {  
    header('Content-type: ' . $mime_type);
    while(!feof($file)) { print(($buffer = fread($file,4096))); }
    fclose($file);
    exit;
} else {
//Generage a new image and save it
   imagepng($image,$cache_filename); //Saves it to the given folder

//Send image
   header('Content-type: ' . $mime_type);
   imagepng($image);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [phpThumb](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/)? It has tons of options for image generation and caching.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to do any iteration when reading the file from the cache, a simple call to readfile() is sufficient.  E.g:

```
if (file_exists($image_path)) {
    // send the cached image to the output buffer (browser)
    readfile($image_path);
}else{
    // create a new image using GD functions
...
```

The full script is here:

http://www.alphadevx.com/a/57-Implementing-an-Image-Cache-for-PHP-GD

Answer (score 0):

Save it to disk. Webserver will take care of caching.

Comment: I usually found cache into hash forms. Is webserver also take care of hashing? Can you explain or give an example how webserver take care of caching.

Comment: By it's purpose. It were designed to cache, as it HTTP server and HTTP protocol support caching. It manages to calculate a hash.